# Razor pay integration in CI

Tags: codeigniter, payment-gateway

I am trying to integrate Razorpay paymentgetway in my webapplication which i am building in CI( codeigniter frame work ) with REST Controller .

I used Razorpay reference code  snippet but it is showing error in "USE" Key word.

An uncaught Exception was encountered

Type: ParseError

Message: syntax error, unexpected 'use' (T_USE)

Filename: /var/www/html/...../...../,,,,/api/......php

My code is as follow  which i am using is given below in PHP CI controller

```
class Manage_Po extends REST_Controller {

    function __construct() {

        require_once (APPPATH . '../assets/razorpay-php/Razorpay.php');

        use Razorpay\Api\Api;

        }
```

public function paymentrazor($dataPaytoken)
    {

```
     $api = new Api('rzp_test_oP14587HtL3lOEov4scw2', 'PdzPtvjZhku2210pHVQytsds44w7Fu');

    if (isset($dataPaytoken['PayToken']) === false) {
        die("Payment id not provided");
    }

    $id = $dataPaytoken['PayToken'] ;

    echo json_encode($payment->toArray());
}
```

function payorder_post() {

```
$data=$this->input->post();


if($data['status'] == 'true'){
    $this->paymentrazor($data['PayToken']);
}
```

}

}

Answer (score 1):

Can you try like prefixed '\'. Sorry this can be answered via comments but I don't have enough privileges to do that.

```
use \Razorpay\Api\Api;
```